# Can the first derivative test be used to find concavity of a graph?

Tags: derivatives

If the first derivative test determines that the left side of a point is increasing, and that the right side of a point is decreasing, can I say that the point is a relative maxima and that the shape of the graph is a concave down?

Reasoning:
If first derivative is obtainable, the critical point cannot be a point of non-differentialibity. And as such, cannot have any other curve except for one that results in a gradient of 0 which would be a concave down.

Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: $f'$ increasing on the left and decreasing on the right sounds more like a point of inflection

Comment: I would be describing the original graph. Not the first derivative graph.

Comment: While the conclusion about "a relative maxim[um]" can be drawn, the concavity of the graph is not implied by this information.

Comment: consider $f'(x) = -x |\sin(\frac 1 x)|$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$. $f$ has a maximum at $x=0$, but is not concave in any neighborhood of $x=0$.

Comment: It is a good hint. Basically you are right, but you need to verify that at this point the first derivative is ZERO. Think about a function that the first derivative at this point is infinity, from the left it tends to Positive infinity and on the right negative one. 1/sin(x).